# View Validation.ErrorTemplate during design time

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

Is there a way to view what the custom ErrorTemplate looks like during design? Currently I can only see how the custom ErrorTemplate looks like during runtime. I am setting the design context and design data with invalid values but the ErrorTemplate does not show up in the visual studio 2010 designer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Expression Blend makes it MUCH easier. With blend just open the template for the control in question, click the "States" tab to reveal your states and choose Invalid/InvalidFocused/InvalidUnFocused and you'll be able to do your necessary design to it visually. Otherwise you'll have to dig through the State values in the VisualStateManager code in the XAML and look up the color codes and find what part of the templates activated for invalid states etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying that doing this allows you to view the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` in Blend?  I've followed your steps but its only showing me VSM ValidationStates (which happen to be empty), not the `ErrorTemplate` that I have defined. How can we view the actual `ErrorTemplate` ControlTemplate that WPF applies when the `IDataErrorInfo` pipeline says there is an error?